# How to make element comparison between two lists more efficient? (TF-IDF)

Tags: python

I have been learning how TF-IDF is calculated and tried to program it myself. I have solved the problem but I assume that there has to be a more efficient way to calculate the answer. I have tried testing it on quite a bit larger datasets and it seems like this function is causing a major bottleneck

```
import math


def calc_idf(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs):  # TODO there must be a way to make this more efficient
    dict_idf = {}
    for i in range(len(normalized_list)):
        dict_calc_idf = []
        for word in normalized_list[i]:
            for x in range(len(terms_with_freqs)):
                print(terms_with_freqs[x][0])
                if word[0] == terms_with_freqs[x][0]:
                    dict_calc_idf.append(
                        (word[0], math.log(doc_length / terms_with_freqs[x][1], 10)))
        dict_idf[i] = dict_calc_idf
    return dict_idf


normalized_list = {0: [('tom', 0.5), ('earns', 0.5)], 1: [('tom', 0.5), ('castaignede', 0.5)], 2: [('aussie', 0.5), ('mcgrath', 0.5)], 3: [('european', 0.5), ('medal', 0.5)]}
terms_with_freqs = [('tom', 2), ('earns', 1), ('castaignede', 1), ('aussie', 1), ('mcgrath', 1), ('european', 1), ('medal', 1)]
doc_length = len(normalized_list)

dict = calc_idf(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs)

print(dict)
```

Comment: At a very quick glance, you should probably be using a dict for `terms_with_freqs`.

Comment: Also, `word[1]`, i.e. the 0.5 from e.g. `('tom', 0.5)` is not used for anything – are you sure your implementation is correct?

Comment: The variable normalized_list, even though it's named as such, is actually a dict. You iterate over a dict using normalized_list.items(). In any case, it seems that it would be simpler if it was just a list. If you need the keys (0, 1, 2 and 3 in your case) you can just use enumerate() in the for loop call.

Comment: @AKX According to wiki you calculate IDF : "log(number of documents / number of documents where the term t appears)" So the number shouldnt be used for calculation? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @MariusKuzm I'm not sure I can answer that comment. It's hard to tell where you've gotten `normalized_list` and `terms_with_freqs` from in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting out of C++-thinking-mode and Pythonizing all that `range(len(...))` stuff roughly halves the running time:

```
def calc_idf2(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs):  # TODO there must be a way to make this more efficient
    dict_idf = {}
    for key, words in normalized_list.items():
        dict_calc_idf = []
        for word, discarded_number in words:
            for term, freq in terms_with_freqs:
                #print(term)
                if word == term:
                    dict_calc_idf.append( (term, math.log(doc_length / freq, 10)) )
        dict_idf[key] = dict_calc_idf
    return dict_idf
```

From IPython's `%timeit` (after commenting out the `print` call):

```
In [10]: timeit calc_idf(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs)                                                                                                            
15.8 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [11]: timeit calc_idf2(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs)                                                                                                           
8.15 µs ± 67.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The next optimization is to avoid the double-loop to match `word` with `term`. That's clearly computationally equivalent to a simple dictionary lookup.  So, express `terms_with_freqs` as a `dict` initially, then:

```
def calc_idf2b(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs):
    dict_idf = {}
    for key, words in normalized_list.items():
        dict_calc_idf = []
        for word, discarded_number in words:
            freq = terms_with_freqs[ word ]
            dict_calc_idf.append( (word, math.log(doc_length / freq, 10)) )
        dict_idf[key] = dict_calc_idf
    return dict_idf
```

To test:

```
In [31]: terms_with_freqs_dict = dict(terms_with_freqs)                                                                                                                            

In [32]: timeit calc_idf2b(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs_dict)                                                                                                     
5.61 µs ± 256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This should be more than merely a proportional increase in speed. Since we've replaced a needlessly nested loop with lower-computational-complexity dictionary lookup, the algorithm should now also scale better to larger data-set sizes.

In the end you'll want to construct `terms_with_freqs_dict` from scratch as a dictionary, rather than composing it as a list and then converting.   You could also pre-compute each `math.log(freq, 10)` in that dictionary instead of using raw frequencies, and precompute `math.log(doc_length, 10)` since that doesn't change over the course of your loops.  Then inside the loop, just subtract one from the other (subtracting logs is the same as dividing then logging):

```
def calc_idf3(normalized_list, terms_with_logged_freqs):
    ldl = math.log(len(normalized_list), 10)
    return { key : [
        ( word, ldl - terms_with_logged_freqs[word] )
        for word, discarded_number in words
    ] for key, words in normalized_list.items() }
```

Presumed preprocessing:

```
terms_with_logged_freqs = { term : math.log(freq, 10) for term, freq in terms_with_freqs }
```

Test:

```
In [43]: timeit calc_idf3(normalized_list, terms_with_logged_freqs)                                                                                                                
3.62 µs ± 25.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: This does not address the fact that OP's `terms_with_freqs` is obviously a dict disguised as a list :)

Comment: @AKX Indeed, but whether it should be turned into a dict or turned into something *else* will depend on whether that `discarded_number` is truly redundant or is being discarded erroneously (per your other comment).

Comment: OP is trying to calculate TF/IDF. The function above is only calculating the IDF part. The `discarded_number` seems to be the TF part.

Comment: @jez would you be able to suggest any places where I could learn more "Pythonizing". Yes, the values are not used. Thanks btw

Comment: @MariusKuzm  See the edit: the algorithm complexity can be reduced.  The word people generally use for code that follows the Zen of Python is "Pythonic", which has the advantage of being nicely googleable.  If you search for "coding pythonically" for example, you get a number of good and not-so-good blog posts that teach exactly that.

Comment: your calc_idf2b() is 70 times faster than calc_idf2() on the dataset I am using. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in the comments, your use of data types in not ideal.

`normalized_list` is currently a dict with lists, but should really be a list of lists. `terms_with_freqs` would be much more efficiently expressed as a dict.

By doing this, you can eliminate at least one of the nested loops. Also, you can eliminate a lot of the `range(len(...))` calls.

The below code gives the same result as your original:

```
import math


def calc_idf(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs):  # TODO there must be a way to make this more efficient
    dict_idf = {}

    for i, word_list in enumerate(normalized_list):
        dict_calc_idf = []
        for word, word_freq in word_list:
            dict_calc_idf.append(
                (word, math.log(doc_length / terms_with_freqs[word], 10)))
        dict_idf[i] = dict_calc_idf
    return dict_idf


normalized_list = [[('tom', 0.5), ('earns', 0.5)], [('tom', 0.5), ('castaignede', 0.5)], [('aussie', 0.5), ('mcgrath', 0.5)], [('european', 0.5), ('medal', 0.5)]]
terms_with_freqs = {'tom': 2, 'earns': 1, 'castaignede': 1, 'aussie': 1, 'mcgrath': 1, 'european': 1, 'medal': 1}
doc_length = len(normalized_list)

dict = calc_idf(doc_length, normalized_list, terms_with_freqs)

print(dict)
```

However, you are already looping over your sentences to generate `normalized_list` in the first place. Can't you calculate IDF in that loop? If you need to generate `terms_with_freqs`, you can use `collections.Counter` which would give you a dict already. The application would be something like:

```
from collections import Counter

terms_with_freqs = Counter(your_text.split())
```